# Facing packets drops in pcap plus plus library

Tags: c++, networking, pcap, packet-capture

I am using pcap++ library for listening to high-frequency tcp data. The library has been dropping packets recently. I need to know its buffer size and how to increase its size.

I tried going through the source code but couldn't find how the memory/buffer was allocated.

Comment: TCP guarantees complete, in-order data delivery, It is expected that IP packets will be lost, but TCP will note missing segments and request that they be resent. If you are losing data, then it is in the OS or application.